# Chargers for NI-CD versus NI-MH batteries

Tags: powertools

Is it safe to use an original DeWalt 9 volt battery charger (DW9118) made for NI-CD batteries on a non-OEM NI-MH type 9 volt battery made for DeWalt products?

Answer (score 1):

There is a small, but non-zero, risk of overcharging NiMH batteries when using a NiCd charger.
The charge profiles of NiCd vs NiMH are very similar but not quite the same, since the 'peak' in the NiMH profile is less pronounced than for NiCd.
It's possible that a NiCd charger will miss it and carry on trying to charge a NiMH which is already full.